# Unable to start a fragment bundle while using JSP with OSGi

Tags: java, jsp, osgi, bundle, fragment

So, I am trying to use JSP and JSTL to build the UI to work with OSGi environment. I've added the required bundle for the JSTL to work: -

- [com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl_1.2.0.v20110728](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl&version=1.2.0.v20110728&searchType=bundlesBySymbolicName&searchQuery=JSTL)

I have also added all the required bundle in the environment. At the end, solving the following dependencies, I end up adding too many bundles, but I am stuck at one point.

One of my bundle (I think that is a fragment), is not getting started, and it's dependency is not getting resolved. The *exception* which I get is: -

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: A fragment bundle cannot be started: com.springsource.org.apache.jasper_7.0.26 [107]
```

And following this exception, I've got one more exception: -

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.0.v20070607 [117]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.apache.jasper.servlet; version="0.0.0"
```

I've following list of bundles installed, some of them are not `Active`: -

```
id  State       Bundle
0   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.1.R37x_v20110808-1106
6   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.persistence.core_2.3.2.v20111125-r10461
10  ACTIVE      javax.persistence_2.0.3.v201010191057
12  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.persistence.antlr_2.3.2.v20111125-r10461
15  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.0.1.v20121003-ad44345
16  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.persistence.asm_2.3.2.v20111125-r10461
21  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.persistence.jpa_2.3.2.v20111125-r10461
25  ACTIVE      StockControlSystem_0.0.1
28  ACTIVE      javax.annotation_1.1.0.v201105051105
32  ACTIVE      org.springframework.core_3.0.5.RELEASE
33  ACTIVE      org.springframework.aop_3.0.5.RELEASE
34  ACTIVE      com.scs.request_1.0.0.qualifier
35  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.virgo.util.common_3.0.1.RELEASE
37  ACTIVE      com.scs.order_1.0.0.qualifier
38  ACTIVE      org.springframework.osgi.io_1.2.1
41  ACTIVE      mysql.jdbc_1.0.0
45  ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.tomcat.api_7.0.26
47  ACTIVE      org.springframework.osgi.core_1.2.1
48  ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging_1.1.1
49  ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.batch_3.6.1
53  ACTIVE      com.scs.persistence_1.0.0.qualifier
55  ACTIVE      com.scs.stockdetails_1.0.0.qualifier
58  ACTIVE      com.scs.delivery_1.0.0.qualifier
59  ACTIVE      org.springframework.beans_3.0.5.RELEASE
60  ACTIVE      org.springframework.context_3.0.5.RELEASE
66  ACTIVE      joda.time_1.0.0
67  ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.aopalliance_1.0.0
71  ACTIVE      javax.servlet_3.0.0.v201103241009
72  ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.xmlcommons_1.3.4
73  ACTIVE      javax.el_2.2.0.v201105051105
74  ACTIVE      javax.servlet.jsp_2.2.0.v201103241009
75  ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl_1.2.0.v20110728
76  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.3.0.v20110513
78  ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.xml.soap_1.3.0
80  RESOLVED    com.springsource.org.apache.coyote_7.0.26
                Master=83
81  ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.activation_1.1.1
82  ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.mail_1.4.0
83  ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.catalina_7.0.26
                Fragments=80, 88, 95, 97
84  ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.persistence_1.0.0
88  RESOLVED    com.springsource.org.apache.catalina.ha_7.0.26
                Master=83
92  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.virgo.util.parser.manifest_3.0.1.RELEASE
93  ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.juli.extras_7.0.26
95  RESOLVED    com.springsource.org.apache.catalina.tribes_7.0.26
                Master=83
97  RESOLVED    com.springsource.org.apache.tomcat.util_7.0.26
                Master=83
100 ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.ejb_3.0.0
101 ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.xml.rpc_1.1.0.v20110517
102 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.util_1.0.300.v20110502
103 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.3.0.v20110502
104 ACTIVE      com.springsource.slf4j.api_1.6.1
                Fragments=113
105 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.virgo.util.math_3.0.1.RELEASE
106 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.virgo.util.io_3.0.1.RELEASE
107 INSTALLED   com.springsource.org.apache.jasper_7.0.26
108 ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.transaction_1.1.0
109 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.virgo.util.osgi_3.0.1.RELEASE
110 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat_2.0.2.RELEASE
111 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.gemini.web.core_2.0.2.RELEASE
112 ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.xml.bind_2.1.7
113 RESOLVED    com.springsource.slf4j.nop_1.6.1
                Master=104
114 ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.xml.stream_1.0.1
115 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.gemini.web.extender_2.0.2.RELEASE
116 ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.el_7.0.26
117 INSTALLED   org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.0.v20070607
```

So, you can see that, `Bundle 107` - `com.springsource.org.apache.jasper_7.0.26` is in installed state, which I think contains the `Missing-Import` Package of the `equinox.jsp.jasper` bundle - `Bundle 117`

After some research, I found that, I need to add some more bundles: -

- `catalina.osgi (5.5.23-SNAPSHOT)`
- `jasper.osgi (5.5.23-SNAPSHOT)`
- `com.springsource.org.apache.taglibs.standard (1.1.2)`

Out of those, I've found the 3rd bundle, but I'm unable to find the first 2 bundles.

Can anyone see what is going on. Have I done something wrong at some place? Or Did I miss to add some bundle? I've been stuck in this issue from the last 2 days, and I think, I'm in no way going to resolve this issue.

One more thing, which I think might be important is, I'm getting these warnings, when I try to start my `Web APP` bundle - `Bundle 25`: -

```
Jan 18, 2013 11:06:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory register
WARNING: Could not get url for /javax/servlet/resources/j2ee_1_4.xsd
Jan 18, 2013 11:06:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory register
WARNING: Could not get url for /javax/servlet/resources/javaee_5.xsd
Jan 18, 2013 11:06:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory register
WARNING: Could not get url for /javax/servlet/resources/javaee_6.xsd
Jan 18, 2013 11:06:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory register
WARNING: Could not get url for /javax/servlet/resources/xml.xsd
Jan 18, 2013 11:06:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory register
WARNING: Could not get url for /javax/servlet/resources/XMLSchema.dtd
```

There are some more warnings like this, but I've skipped them, as there are too many.

I've added as much information, that I think would be needed. But, if you 
need some more information, please ask the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, fragments can never be started as they don't have their own lifecycle. So this is not really an error; you just shouldn't try to start a fragment.

Second, it looks like bundle 117 is indeed failing because of the missing import of package `org.apache.jasper.servlet`, and this package probably comes from the fragment 107 that doesn't resolve. So the challenge is to work out why 107 can't resolve. You can get a clue about this by typing the command `diag 107`; this will print the list of unsatisfied imports for the fragment.

Comment: Thanks @Neil for your reply. I was waiting for it. I tried your command, and it gave me list of missing optional package. So, I added them. Now, I am getting a list of `errors` for `jasper.servlet` bundle, which reads like this: - **`Constraints from the fragment conflict with the host: Import-Package: javax.el; version="[1.0.0,3.0.0)"`**. And there are many more. If you want I would add them to my question. What can be the problem?

Comment: With a little google searching, I reached your blog post - http://njbartlett.name/2011/02/09/uses-constraints.html, which is really very descriptive. I followed that post, and at the end, I found that I was having two version of a package in the runtime. One from the `org.eclipse.osgi` and one from the `springsource.xmlcommon`. Later on I found that I don't need that springsource bundle, as the version imported by the bundle `107` was being exported by `org.osgi`. So, I removed the springsource bundle.

Comment: But, I'm still getting the same issue. And this time, I can't find any package with multiple version roaming around. And now I'm stuck. What to do?? :( :(

Comment: Oh dear. Is it possible to try running this on Felix instead of Equinox? Felix has better diagnostic messages for uses-constraint violations. You can always switch back to Equinox after fixing the problem.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. This is NOT a uses-constraint violation. It says that the constraints (i.e. imports) of the fragment conflict with the host. The intended host bundle must be importing a disjoint range for package `javax.el`. There isn't a good fix for this, the fragment simply seems to be invalid because it shouldn't attach to a host that it's incompatible with.

Comment: Thanks Neil. I think you were right. In my `catalina` host, when I tweaked it's MANIFEST file, and added those missing imports, then it worked. Then I downloaded a new `catalina` host, and that problem is resolved. But now, I'm facing one another problem, majorly related to `JSTL` bundles. Can you take a look into this question: - http://stackoverflow.com/q/14459873/1679863

Answer (score 0):

It might not be pleasant for you, but if you use Pax-Web instead of Gemini, it'll work with jsp right away.

Pax-Web can be found at http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=pax%20web&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fteam.ops4j.org%2Fwiki%2Fdisplay%2Fpaxweb%2FPax%2BWeb&ei=-WT6UITsL4mItQbw_IGICA&usg=AFQjCNFWWNAvM4nxEqoqVnlL14P3gt2aLw&sig2=Q7fVwc6mjMN68ErFbhTDEA&bvm=bv.41248874,d.Yms

It looks to me, like you are building a complete container. Ever considered using either Apache Karaf or Eclipse Virgo?
Karaf is also awailable with a minimal set, containing only the basics.