# Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, osgi, taglib

So I was working with JSTL in OSGi, under Gemini runtime. And I'm getting following exception, when I try to access the url to my `servlet`: -

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/login.jsp (line: 3, column: 66) Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld" from JAR file "file:/D:/OSGi%20Runtime/Gemini/gemini-web/dep/com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.0.v20110728.jar": org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV
```

However, I have checked, that I already have all the necessary bundles in my runtime. The relevant bundle that I have is: -

```
71  ACTIVE      javax.servlet_3.0.0.v201103241009
73  ACTIVE      javax.el_2.2.0.v201105051105
74  ACTIVE      javax.servlet.jsp_2.2.0.v201103241009
75  ACTIVE      com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl_1.2.0.v20110728
121 ACTIVE      com.springsource.org.apache.taglibs.standard_1.1.2.v20110517
```

There are more bundles, but those are the ones that are relevant. So, I can't understand what went wrong.

From the [Spring Source Repository](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/), from where I downloaded the bundle, it's clear that, [org.apache.taglibs.standard](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl&version=1.2.0.v20110728&searchType=bundlesBySymbolicName&searchQuery=com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl) bundle - *Bundle 121*, contains that `JstlCoreTLV class`.
So, not sure, what's going on here.

Here's my `JSP` header I'm using (Just in case, it is relevant): -

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

I'm using: -

- `Servlet 3.0`
- `JSP 2.2`
- `Gemini Runtime 2.1`
- `JSTL 1.2.0`

---

**Update: -**

The problem described below seems to be solved, and now I'm not getting any warning as shown below. That was because, I was having the `taglibs.standard_1.1.2` - (**Bundle 121**), which was incompatible to others. So, I removed it, and the warnings went away.

So, you can ignore whatever is there from here on. But, The problem above is still there. I'm still getting that `JasperException`. May be this will help further, as the problem domain is reduced now a little bit thanks to the valuable input from @BalusC.

---

**Part after this is solved. So, you can ignore it: -**

Also, I'm not sure that the version of the OSGi JSTL bundle that I have - `Bundle 75`, is compatible with the other bundles - `javax.el`, `taglibs`, `servlets`, etc, or not. Because I was using `JSTL 1.2.1`, but I couldn't get the bundle for `JSTL 1.2.1`. What I got was the bundle I used (`JSTL 1.2.0`). Why this is bothering me is because of these kinds of messages coming up, when I start my application: -

```
Jan 22, 2013 7:14:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Jan 22, 2013 7:14:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Jan 22, 2013 7:14:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Jan 22, 2013 7:14:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Jan 22, 2013 7:14:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Jan 22, 2013 7:14:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
```

As you can see that there two different URLs shown above: -

- URI: `http://java.sun.com/jstl/core`
- URI: `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core`

Now, AFAIK both those URLs, do not belong to same `JSTL` versions.
So, could that raise some problems? And what can be the reason for them to come? I have just used one `JSTL bundle`.

Comment: Have you checked about JSTL in [it's SO wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)? It could help you to solve this riddle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl_1.2.0.v20110728
com.springsource.org.apache.taglibs.standard_1.1.2.v20110517
```

You're mixing JSTL 1.2.0 API+impl with JSTL 1.1.2 impl.

The both impls are conflicting with each other which explains all the trouble you're seeing.

Get rid of the 1.1.2 impl.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Comment: Thanks @BalusC for the response. I removed the `taglibs.standard` bundle, since the packages it exports was conflicting with the packages exported by first bundle. Surprisingly, the exception is the same. No success :( :(

Comment: No dirty deploy? Are you able to explore `/WEB-INF/lib` of the baked WAR/deploy?

Comment: @BalusC.. Sorry I didn't understand your last line. You mean explore `/WEB-INF/lib` inside the `WAR` file?

Comment: Yes, sorry for asking in somewhat overgeneric terms, I've never worked with OSGi before.

Comment: It's absolutely no problem. Actually, I'm seeing myself moving towards a solution here now. :) I re-exported my WebApp as WAR, and updated my environment with the new WAR file. And now, I'm not getting those warning I posted in OP. And also, the `context` is now getting initialized properly by the Listener. Earlier, it was not. But, again, when I go on to fire the URL, that creepy exception is there only.

Comment: Sure that you're not looking at a cached request/response? Have you confirmed that `standard.jar` isn't present in exported WAR anymore?

Comment: FYI, I now have following 4 bundles, in my environment, related to Servlet, JSP, and JSTL: - `javax.servlet_3.0.0.v201103241009, javax.el_2.2.0.v201105051105, javax.servlet.jsp_2.2.0.v201103241009, com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl_1.2.0.v20110728`. If you want to see the packages they export or import, I'll post the link to `springsource` in the next comments.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a part of it now. Actually I never added it to the Build Path. But only to the `target runtime`. And now I removed it from the runtime. So, it's not there.

Comment: Now, for all of those 4 bundles, when I see the exported and imported packages, I don't see any version conflict between them.

Comment: These are the `imported package` of the `WAR file`: - **`javax.servlet;version="3.0.0",
 javax.servlet.http;version="3.0.0",
 javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt;version="1.2.0.v20110728",
 javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql;version="1.2.0.v20110728",
 javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv;version="1.2.0.v20110728",
 javax.servlet.jsp.resources;version="2.2.0",
 javax.servlet.jsp.tagext;version="2.2.0",
 javax.servlet.resources;version="3.0.0",
`**

Comment: I've never worked with OSGi, so I have no idea what's going on, but normally you should not end up with container-specific libraries in `/WEB-INF/lib`. You can also get this kind of exception when the container already ships with JSTL by itself (like Glassfish and JBoss). You should only provide JSTL along with the webapp when the container doesn't ship with it (like Tomcat and Jetty). But for none of those containers you've to bundle JSP/Servlet/EL along. So having JSP/Servlet/EL libraries in webapp is also somewhat strange. But again, OSGi is completely beyond me.

Comment: @BalusC.. One important confirmation, will `JSTL 1.2.0` work with `Servlet 3.0`? In the Wiki page, it's written that `JSTL 1.2` ships with `Servlet 2.5` and can work with `Servlet 2.4` also. Can this be a problem?

Comment: Yes, JSTL 1.2.0 is compatible with Servlet 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark. Not sure if you came upon below links.

The error message you posted "Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV" seems to be pretty common.

From this link :
http://christerblog.wordpress.com/2010/05/04/tag-library-woes-deploying-war-on-tomcat-6/

Do you have any conflicting/incompatible jar libraries in your WAR file ?

Another one here also points to incompatible jars in the build path:
[Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452403/unable-to-read-tld-meta-inf-c-tld)

Comment: Thanks @Zenil.. but I already visited that SO link. It didn't help. As far as conflicting/incompatible Jar is concerned, I have checked it 10 times. There are no incompatibility. :( :(

Comment: @Rohit . Can you post the full stacktrace ? I saw another link which eventually traced this issue to a ClassCastExeption . That was because his tomcat common lib had jsp-api.jar incompatible with his application jar . http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2005/1/27/frustrating-tomcat-5-5-x-issue-solved-conflicting-jars

Comment: Sorry bro. I can only post stack trace, when I reach my office tomorrow.

Comment: The commonality of this error message continues to make me believe that its a jar issue..Hang in there..:)-

Comment: Well, wherever I tried to search for a solution, I only got this as solution. But, unfortunately, I've not been able to find any incomaptible JAR file. Still I'll see for it again tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from `Tomcat 8` to `Tomcat 9`, which has `125: jstl.jar,taglibs-standard-spec-*.jar,` in its `catalina.properties`. Does this mean that jstl is preinstalled, unlike tomcat 8 where `jstl 1.2` was needed in the `build.gradle` ?

Since I had to remove the following lines to get it working

```
//compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.0'
//compile group: 'javax.servlet.jsp.jstl', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
```

If my answer is incorrect, please let me know I am happy to delete it. Since @BalusC answer gave me the clue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same issue with my JSP file.

Server - Tomcat 10

I removed the tag lib (below) from my JSP and it worked for me

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I don't think I can really answer this question, no idea if this is relevant to you.

I've struggled with this problem too, until I switched to [Pax Web](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxweb/Pax+Web). It worked pretty much out of the box. I *intended* to go back and figure out exactly why my previous setup did not work, but, well, it never happened.

So, if it is possible in your situation, use Pax Web over hand picking your own bundles.

Comment: Thanks @Frank for your response. PaxWeb seems to be interesting. But again, if I think of switching to use it, it would be little bit tough for me to switch my complete project from Equinox to Pax Web. Further more, as it's a project related task, so I doubt I could switch to it. Still I'll consider it. But of course, that would be my last bet. Not even sure, because rather than switching to `PaxWeb` for my current project, I would rather prefer to switch from `JSP` to `Adobe Flex` for UI purpose, which we have done till now. That would be easy for me.

Comment: But you have given me a new thing to look into. May be I can try it out in my next project. Thanks for that. But for now, I wish if someone could really help me crack this `Equinox` Stuff.

Comment: Sorry I mean `Gemini` wherever I said `Equinox` in my previous two comments.

Comment: Yeah, I expected that. Hang in there, someone out there will be able to help you!