# javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

Hi I am working on a project which uses struts2 and hibernate . Here is the error that has been baffling me :

> Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
>
> **Messages**:  javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator
>   javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator
>   File: java/net/URLClassLoader.java Line number:   372

the full stacktrace is given below :

```
    Aug 15, 2016 12:41:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1251)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.createValidator(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:347)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:194)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:421)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:479)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1435)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:139)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:227)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:100)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache./catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:164)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:188)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:369)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:273)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:76)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:125)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:253)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at 

    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[Here is the list of jars included in Web-Inf/Lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsjsp.jpg)
[Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsTDZ.jpg)

```
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/asm-5.0.2.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/asm-commons-5.0.2.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/com.sun.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201004141950.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.0.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.5.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-digester-2.1.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-2.2.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-javaflow-20060411.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang3-3.2.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang3-3.4-javadoc.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/eclipselink.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/freemarker-2.3.19.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/gson-2.3.1.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.9.Final.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/itext-2.1.7.js4.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.1.4.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.1.4.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.1.4.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jasperreports-6.2.0.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/javax.activation_1.1.0.v201108011116.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/javax.mail_1.4.0.v201005080615.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/javax.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201105210648.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/javax.xml.stream_1.0.1.v201004272200.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ognl-3.0.6.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/org.eclipse.persistence.jpars_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/postgresql-9.4.1207.jre6.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.20.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.20.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-jasperreports-plugin-2.3.24.1.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-json-plugin-2.3.20.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
/timesheet/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/xwork-core-2.3.20.jar
```

I have viewed all other posts regarding this and tried all solutions mentioned in them .Different than NoClassDefFoundError.
Any help is deeply appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Which server you are deploying and what is the version of that server?

Comment: I am using tomcat 8

Comment: Please post the list of jars in side you `WEB-INF\lib` folder

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I have edited the question with the list of jars.Please take a look.

Comment: Hi just do dir and post the output as text.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam  Posted again as text.

Comment: @AsteriskNinja I have tried those solutions. Didn't work.

Comment: add servlet.jar and if that didn't work try adding all jars to deployment descriptor

Comment: @AsteriskNinja adding servlet.jar didn't work. and i don't know how to add jars to deployment descriptor. please provide the detailed steps in eclipse neon.
i also tried googling it but couldn't find a valid solution.

Comment: rightclick on project>build path>configurt build path>deployment descriptor/assembly>add java entries from path>select all>ok then try

Comment: @AsteriskNinja tried it , didn't work . My friend has same code and same jars in his laptop,  but it's working fine in his one and not in fine . I am really fed up now . Please help

Comment: @AsteriskNinja FYI i have compared the console of my friend and mine. The difference is that in his logs there are 14 hibernate entries whereas mine has just 7. What could be the reason ?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Please help me with this situation.

Comment: My problem was resolved by using Eclipse mars 2 .  I was using neon earlier. I don't know how that happened.

Comment: @Tunaki My question is different because it is pretty specific problem of NoClassDefFound error not like the general one you suggested.

Comment: A NoClassDefFoundError like you have has the same resolution in all cases. It means you're missing a library inside WEB-INF/lib, like the linked question suggests.

Comment: @Tunaki I want you to tell me which library i am missing or remove the duplicate tag from my question.

Comment: @Tunaki Remove the duplicate tag as it is not an exact duplicate of your mentioned question and reopen my question.

Comment: Looking at your dependencies, I see `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar` and `jstl-1.2.jar`. That's one too many here. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459873/failed-to-load-or-instantiate-taglibraryvalidator-class-org-apache-taglibs-stan Please read the duplicate question as it will explain to you exactly why this error is happening; yes, it won't provide you with copy-paste solution, but it will explain the issue.